# TODOIST API: How to get list of users to assign a specific user to task?

Tags: api, todoist

It seems that API allows to assign users to a task (called an Item in the API) using the body field `responsible_uid` at the [add an item](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/#add-an-item) endpoint. However I cannot find a way **to list user uids** or any other way to get user details anywhere in API documentation.

Official python library [todoist-python](https://pypi.org/project/todoist-python/) doesn't provide any way to do this either. So for now it seems I can only create tasks without assigning them to anybody, which is a bummer.

Any advise grately appreciated!

Links:

- [Todoist Sync API](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/)
- [Todoist
  REST API](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should first [share a project](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/#share-a-project) and then you can get all collaborators in the [Sync request](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/#sync).